# postgres return undetermined number of columns from a table function

Tags: postgresql

I need a function that meets the following

```
create function testtable() returns table( *filll this automatically* ) language plpgsql`
...

return query select a,b,c from letters
```

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: I have more than 90 fields damn

Comment: If you are returning all columns from that table you can use `returns setof letters`

Comment: If it's all the same datatype, you can return an array.  This is probably overkill and not worth the overhead, but you can also return a JSON or XML object.  If it's all from one table, just return the entire row and let the select from function() determine which columns to choose.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you show me  returns setof